# Какой язык описывает грамматика с правилами?S->S(S)S|e

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Какой язык описывает грамматика с правилами?

```
S->S(S)S|e
```

Нашёл в интернете вот такое решение.

```
L={u|u ∈
 {(,)}* и содержит равное количество открывающихся и закрывающихся скобок }

L={u|u ∈
 {"(",")"}* u-правильная скобочная последовательность }
```

Мне не совсем понятно,что означает вот этот знак | наверное или?
Как этот пример решается получается все большие буквы Нетерминалы(Большие буквы) просто убрали и пустое слово e убрали и оставили только скобки?
В последнем шаге они заменили все буквы S на скобки?
Откуда взялась *?

Comment: В математике запись L = {u|....} означает L - множество из элементов u таких, для которых выполняется ...

Comment: Вобщем, я просто не знаю, как принято доказывать формально, но очевидно, что этот язык описывает любую правильно вложенную последовательность скобок, типа `((()()))()((()))` (или пустую строку как частный случай). За это могу ручаться :) - но это просто ответ, который я вижу интуитивно (для меня это просто очевидно :)). Дискретку не изучал, а потому, как это делается формально - не подскажу, остановлюсь потому на комментарии. Сами смотрите - вы можете добавить любую такую последовательность как префикс, суффикс или поместить ее в скобки...

Comment: Можете подсказать как вы это уведели? ведь тут три буквы S вы как то их заменили?

Comment: Нашёл в интернете такой пример,но тут есть множество условий а тут одно условие https://sun9-34.userapi.com/c850328/v850328874/1c6c11/2F4fkhZiwgk.jpg

Comment: Как то вот так раскрывать её чтоли S(S)S|eS(S)S|eS(S)S|e

Comment: Или Буквы S удаляется мысленно?

Comment: Все S справа могут быть разными... Так что, например, если сначала сделаем подстановку e вместо каждого S справа - получим `()`. Теперь, если использовать эту строку как левую S, а вторую и третью - как e, получим `()()`. Применим эту новую строку как среднее S, а левое и правое заменим на e - получим `(()())`... Ну, как-то так... Буквы S справа заменяются либо на какую-то из валидных строк, либо на пустую строку, и так получается новое валидное значение  S.

Comment: Вот не совсем понятно с этого этапа "Теперь, если использовать эту строку как левую S". помимо e получается можно подставить ,что угодно?

Comment: Не что угодно, а корректные (соответствующие грамматике) строки. Например, никакой подстановкой вы не получите строку `aba` или `)(`. Вместо S можно подставлять строки, которые получаются путем подстановки ранее полученных с помощью того же правила строк.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста процесс подстановки по подробнее показать вот например S->S(S)S|e
Подставляю e заместо S.
S->() а как дальше?

Comment: А дальше - шесть вариантов: S->e(e)e, e(e)(), e(())e, e(())(), ()(e)e, ()(e)(), ()(())e, ()(())() - т.е. строки `() ()() (()) (())() ()() ()()() ()(()) ()(())()` Вывод некоторых строк неоднозначен - например, двух `()()`, но это не меняет тот факт, что это - корректные строки грамматики.

Comment: Спасибо большое))) хоть вы и не написали ответ тут посмотрю как вы другим отвечали может ,что понравится плюсану))